# In UICollectionView, the order changes automatically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a big problem.

I scrolled in the UICollectionView.
When the drawing area is scrolled too much, the arrangement order has become disjointed.

I do not want to change the order even though scrolling.
What should I do?

help me.

```
let titles = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8", "9", "10", "11", "12"] //titles


func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 12
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = testCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TestCell", for: indexPath) as! TestCell //customCell

    let testTitle = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel

    testTitle.text  = titles[indexPath.row]

    return cell // yeah, all done. is these code is normal. right? But when i scroll this UICollection, change the order in Outside drawing area.
}
```

Comment: No it's order never changed. In my previous experience never it's happened

Comment: Thx for comment. Hmm I should rewrite my code : _ (

Comment: If you have a time then wait for others comment. Maybe it's happened  for others!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely not be using `viewWithTag`. The reason for this is because cells are dequeued, which means that cells that have been taken off screen by scrolling are reused for the cells which are about to come on screen. This is done to save memory. Sometimes the problem with the order can be because previously used cells are not updated quick enough when they are presented to the user. The solution to this if you are using a network request can be to firstly to streamline your request and then cache any heavy data that is returned, such as images.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should not be causing the cells to change order. I'm wondering if you have a problem with using `viewWithTag`. That's a fairly fragile way to find views in a collection view/table view cell.

You already have a custom cell type. I would suggest creating an outlet to your label in your custom cell type, and referencing the label that way:

```
class TestCell: UICollectionViewCell {
  //(Connect this outlet in your cell prototype in your Storyboard
  @IBOutlet titleLabel: UILabel! 
}



//And in your view controller's cellForItemAt method...
cell.titleLabel.text = titles[indexPath.row]
```